# Plot symbolic equation using standard plot function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

In order to obtain a graphical representation of the behaviour of a fluid it is common practice to plot its streamlines.

For a given two-dimensional fluid with speed components u = K*x and v = -K*y (where K is a constant, for example: K = 5), the streamline equation can be obtained integrating the flow velocity field components as follows:

Streamline equation: ∫dx/u = ∫dy/v

The solved equation looks like this: A = B + C (where A is the solution of the first integral, B is the solution of the second integral and C is an integration constant).

Once we have achieved this, we can start plotting a streamline by simply assigning a value to C, for example: C = 1, and plotting the resulting equation. That would generate a single streamline, so in order to get more of them you need to iterate this last step assigning a different value of C each time.

I have successfully plotted the streamlines of this particular flow by letting matlab [integrate](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) the equation symbolically and using `ezplot` to produce a graphic as follows:

```
syms x y

K = 5; %Constant.

u = K*x; %Velocity component in x direction.
v = -K*y; %Velocity component in y direction.

A = int(1/u,x); %First integral.
B = int(1/v,y); %Second integral.

for C = -10:0.1:10; %Loop. C is assigned a different value in each iteration.
    eqn = A == B + C; %Solved streamline equation.
    ezplot(eqn,[-1,1]); %Plot streamline.
    hold on;
end

axis equal;
axis([-1 1 -1 1]);
```

This is the result:

[image]

The problem is that for some particular regions of the flow `ezplot` is not accurate enough and doesn't handle singularities very well (asymptotes, etc.). That's why a standard "numeric" `plot` seems desirable, in order to obtain a better visual output.

The challenge here is to convert the symbolic streamline solution into an explicit expression that would be compatible with the standard `plot` function.

I have tried to do it like this, using `subs` and `solve` with no success at all (Matlab throws an error).

```
syms x y

K = 5; %Constant.

u = K*x; %Velocity component in x direction.
v = -K*y; %Velocity component in y direction.

A = int(1/u,x); %First integral.
B = int(1/v,y); %Second integral.

X = -1:0.1:1; %Array of x values for plotting.

for C = -10:0.1:10; %Loop. C is assigned a different value in each iteration.
    eqn = A == B + C; %Solved streamline equation.
    Y = subs(solve(eqn,y),x,X); %Explicit streamline expression for Y.
    plot(X,Y); %Standard plot call.
    hold on;
end
```

This is the error that is displayed on the command window:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Division by zero.
[_power]

Evaluating: symobj::trysubs

Error in sym/subs>mupadsubs (line 139)
G =
mupadmex('symobj::fullsubs',F.s,X2,Y2);

Error in sym/subs (line 124)
G = mupadsubs(F,X,Y);

Error in Flow_Streamlines (line 18)
Y = subs(solve(eqn,y),x,X); %Explicit
streamline expression for Y.
```

So, how should this be done?

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: @Hwathanie Yes, I have edited the post adding the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `subs` many times, `matlabFunction` is more efficient. You can use `C` as a parameter, and solve for `y` in terms of both `x` and `C`. Then the `for` loop is very much faster:

```
syms x y

K = 5; %Constant.

u = K*x; %Velocity component in x direction.
v = -K*y; %Velocity component in y direction.

A = int(1/u,x); %First integral.
B = int(1/v,y); %Second integral.

X = -1:0.1:1; %Array of x values for plotting.

syms C % C is treated as a parameter
eqn = A == B + C; %Solved streamline equation.

% Now solve the eqn for y, and make it into a function of `x` and `C`
Y=matlabFunction(solve(eqn,y),'vars',{'x','C'})

for C = -10:0.1:10; %Loop. C is assigned a different value in each iteration.
    plot(X,Y(X,C)); %Standard plot call, but using the function for `Y`
    hold on;
end
```

Comment: My answer only gives the solutions where `x` and `y` have the same signs, and I can't quite see where to get Matlab to give the other solutions, but you can manually plot them with `plot(X,Y(X,C),X,-Y(X,C));` in the loop.